# c typedef(ed) opaque pointer

Tags: c, struct, typedef, opaque-pointers

I've defined an opaque structure and related APIs like this:

```
typedef struct foo foo;
foo *create_foo(...);
delete_foo(foo *f);
```

I am not able to define the structure in my c file. Gives redefinition error.

```
typedef struct foo {
   int implementation;
}foo;
```

I am able to use foo in c file without typedef but I want the typedef (i.e. use it directly as foo*). Is there a way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You already have the `typedef` in your header, so include that and define `struct foo` in the implementation without the `typedef`.

`foo.h`:

```
typedef struct foo foo;
foo *create_foo(...);
delete_foo(foo *f);
```

`foo.c`:

```
#include <foo.h>

struct foo { int implementation; };
/* etc. */
```

Comment: True. I can just use it in c file without typedefing it again. Dumb of me to ask such question. Thanks for making me realize that. :)